# Instantiate a class from an abstract syntax tree

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a .py file that contains the definition of a class. I cannot change that file.
I have parsed the contents of that file and gotten an abstract syntax tree (ast) for it, more specifically I've got an instance of `ast.ClassDef()`.

How can I instantiate that class from the `ast.ClassDef()`?

Here's a contrived demo showing what I want to do:

```
import ast
src = """
class MyClass():
  def __init__():
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 2
    self.thesum = self.a + self.b
"""
p = ast.parse(src)
class_ = [node for node in ast.walk(p) if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef)][0]
class_  #I want to instantiate the class that is referenced by class_
```

Googling suggests that maybe `compile()` could help but I couldn't get that to work as it seems to expect executable code rather than a class definition. In other words, this didn't do very much:

`exec(compile(class_.body, "fakemodule", 'exec'))`

it throws an error:

> TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

So, how can I instantiate that class?

Comment: Uh, you can execute Python code from within Python. I mean, you can execute the code in _strings_ with `compile`, `eval` or `exec`, depending on the task. That is, there's no need for `ast` at all.

Comment: Thanks, though as I explained (I guess not too well) this contrived demo is just that, a demo. In my real use case I don't have the codesitting there in a here string.
The point is I have a class in a `ast.ClassDef`and I want to instantiate it.